# AD banners/interstitial caching reaches to 6 mb..How can I implement one AD through whole application

Tags: android, caching, admob

My Ads caching reaches 6 mb quite easily on my tablet. I have one banner used on four fragments. and 3 more banners inside different activities that are launched through fragments. Is there a way to use just one Ad/AdRequest through whole application?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using fragments, you can just use a single activity having a single adview.

However, if you still want to use different banners for each fragment's layout, you can use a static method to load the ads:

```
public class MyAdView {
    public static void SetAD(AdView adView){  
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
Usage:

public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private AdView adView;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.caller_main);
        MyAdView.SetAd((AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView));
    }   
}
```